# Derive the gradient through torch.topk

Tags: math, pytorch, gradient

I want to derive the gradient through `torch.topk` function.

Suppose I the input is a vector
[image],

then it is transformed by a parameter matrix
[image] ,

and the top k values of the vector are selected
[image].

The result vector is further transformed by **element-wise multiplication**.
[image]

Finally the loss is computed by

[image].

I wonder, is the loss differentiable with respect to W? Formally, can we calculate the following gradient?

[image]

Comment: `topk` is a differentiable operation in pytorch, which makes your entire pipeline differentiable. You should be able to call `loss.backward()` and then get `W.grad`.

Comment: I know it is differentiable. What I really want to know is how it is differentiable, and the math formulas behind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `topk()` operation is simply a linear transformation to *pick* the *top k* elements of a tensor. Since this is a `W @ X` or matrix-vector multiplication kind of operation, this is also differentiable.

**Example**: Below I have computed the pipelined operation `topk(Wx)` in two ways and showed the gradients resulting from both are identical.

```py
In [1]: import torch

In [2]: x1 = torch.rand(6, requires_grad = True)

In [3]: W1 = torch.rand(6, 6, requires_grad = True)

In [4]: x1
Out[4]: tensor([0.1511, 0.5990, 0.6338, 0.5137, 0.5203, 0.0560], requires_grad=True)

In [5]: W1
Out[5]: 
tensor([[0.2541, 0.6699, 0.5311, 0.7801, 0.5042, 0.5475],
        [0.7523, 0.1331, 0.7670, 0.8132, 0.0524, 0.0269],
        [0.3974, 0.2880, 0.9142, 0.9906, 0.4401, 0.3984],
        [0.7956, 0.2071, 0.2209, 0.6192, 0.2054, 0.7693],
        [0.8587, 0.8415, 0.6033, 0.3812, 0.2498, 0.9813],
        [0.9033, 0.0417, 0.2272, 0.1576, 0.9087, 0.3284]], requires_grad=True)

In [6]: y1 = W1 @ x1

In [7]: y1
Out[7]: tensor([1.4699, 1.1260, 1.5721, 0.8523, 1.3969, 0.8776], grad_fn=<MvBackward>)

In [8]: yk, _ = torch.topk(y1, 3)

In [9]: yk
Out[9]: tensor([1.5721, 1.4699, 1.3969], grad_fn=<TopkBackward>)

In [10]: loss1 = (yk ** 2).sum()

In [11]: loss1.backward()

In [12]: W1.grad
Out[12]: 
tensor([[0.4442, 1.7609, 1.8633, 1.5102, 1.5296, 0.1646],
        [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
        [0.4751, 1.8833, 1.9928, 1.6152, 1.6359, 0.1760],
        [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
        [0.4222, 1.6734, 1.7706, 1.4352, 1.4535, 0.1564],
        [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000]])
```

Now let us evaluate the same set of operations but using `topk()` as a linear transformation explicitly. Note that the constructed `Wk` matrix selectively picks out top k (here 3) elements from the 6 element tensor through multiplication.

```py
In [13]: x2 = torch.tensor([0.1511, 0.5990, 0.6338, 0.5137, 0.5203, 0.0560], req
    ...: uires_grad=True)

In [14]: W2 = torch.tensor([[0.2541, 0.6699, 0.5311, 0.7801, 0.5042, 0.5475],
    ...:         [0.7523, 0.1331, 0.7670, 0.8132, 0.0524, 0.0269],
    ...:         [0.3974, 0.2880, 0.9142, 0.9906, 0.4401, 0.3984],
    ...:         [0.7956, 0.2071, 0.2209, 0.6192, 0.2054, 0.7693],
    ...:         [0.8587, 0.8415, 0.6033, 0.3812, 0.2498, 0.9813],
    ...:         [0.9033, 0.0417, 0.2272, 0.1576, 0.9087, 0.3284]], requires_gra
    ...: d=True)

In [15]: y2 = W2 @ x2

In [16]: y2
Out[16]: tensor([1.4700, 1.1260, 1.5721, 0.8523, 1.3969, 0.8776], grad_fn=<MvBackward>)

# Use the indices obtained earlier to construct the matrix
In [19]: _
Out[19]: tensor([2, 0, 4])

In [20]: k = 3

In [21]: Wk = torch.zeros(k, y2.shape[0])

In [22]: Wk[torch.arange(k), _] = 1

In [23]: Wk.requires_grad = True

In [24]: Wk
Out[24]: 
tensor([[0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.]], requires_grad=True)


In [25]: yk2 = Wk @ y2

In [26]: yk2
Out[26]: tensor([1.5721, 1.4700, 1.3969], grad_fn=<MvBackward>)

In [27]: loss2 = (yk2 ** 2).sum()

In [28]: loss2.backward()
```

Now compare the gradients obtained in both cases:

```py
In [29]: W2.grad
Out[29]: 
tensor([[0.4442, 1.7611, 1.8634, 1.5103, 1.5297, 0.1646],
        [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
        [0.4751, 1.8834, 1.9929, 1.6152, 1.6360, 0.1761],
        [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
        [0.4222, 1.6735, 1.7707, 1.4352, 1.4536, 0.1565],
        [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000]])

In [30]: W1.grad
Out[30]: 
tensor([[0.4442, 1.7609, 1.8633, 1.5102, 1.5296, 0.1646],
        [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
        [0.4751, 1.8833, 1.9928, 1.6152, 1.6359, 0.1760],
        [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
        [0.4222, 1.6734, 1.7706, 1.4352, 1.4535, 0.1564],
        [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000]])

In [31]: x1.grad
Out[31]: tensor([4.3955, 5.2256, 6.1213, 6.4732, 3.5637, 5.6037])

In [32]: x2.grad
Out[32]: tensor([4.3957, 5.2261, 6.1215, 6.4733, 3.5641, 5.6040])
```

As you can see the results are identical upto some floating point errors which were introduced when I copied the values of `x1` and `W1` without taking their full precision.

Comment: Okay I got clear explanation of `torch.topk` is differentiable. However, I do need something mathematical, which means some math formula of the gradient received by the input x. Could you please help me with that? To clarify, I have the math basis for difference, but I'm not an expert, and I cannot find a detailed tutorial on Internet about calculating the gradient with respect to some sparse vectors. Could you please help me with that? Or maybe do you know some tutorials about that?

Comment: Do you know how gradient (back) propagates through matrix multiplication kind of things? Like how you get the gradients `dLoss/dW` or `dLoss/dx` from the upstream scalar `Loss` when there are `y = Wx` and `Loss = someScalarFunc(y)` kind of equations?

Comment: Not much. And I'm confused about that. I can only recall chain rule.

Comment: Then you should start from this [tutorial](https://cs231n.github.io/optimization-2/). Try to fully understand it.

Comment: Thank you very much! May I turn to you when I encounter problems?

Comment: Sure, you can comment here.

Comment: This resource really helps me a lot. It lets me know Jacobian and provides helpful insights about backpropagation. However, one thing still perplex me is the local gradient $\frac{\partial A}{\partial C}$ for the following equation: $A = B \circ (C < 0.2)$ where $\circ$ denotes Hadamard Multiplication and $A,B,C\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$. I've checked some answers suggesting the equivalence between Hadamard Multiplication and Diagonal Matrix Multiplication, however they are related with vector hadamard production, and it's not what I want.

Comment: Hey the math is not correctly formatted in comments. I think you should ask it as a separate question.

Comment: I asked the question in StackExchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4146359/derivative-for-masked-matrix-hadamard-multiplication

Comment: I think this question is similar to how [gradient propagates through relu](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/19272/deep-neural-network-backpropogation-with-relu).

Comment: thank you swag, I'm trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out thanks to @swag2198 and I posted the formulation on [my repository](https://github.com/namespace-Pt/News-Recommendation/blob/main/Codes/manual/SFI-gradient-formulate.ipynb)